# My contact form will not work

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts, contact-form

I have a contact form that will not work I've been trying to get it to work for months trying different tutorials with no luck.

please [take a look here](http://bit.ly/16vHlwe)

I followed [this tutorial](http://bit.ly/1b4AvEO) this time

THIS IS THE CODE I HAV ON THE FROM THE FIRST LINK EXACTLY THE SAME!
    
    
    **Contact Form**

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td width="16%">Subject</td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
 <td width="82%"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="50"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Detail</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset"     name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

AND THE PHP:

```
<?php

// Contact subject
$subject ="$subject";

 // Details
$message="$detail";


// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail";

// From
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";


// Enter your email address
$to ='contact@kieshajewel.com';

$send_contact='mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)';


// Check, if message sent to your email
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
echo "We've recived your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

All I want is a simple contact form something like below: and the correct php to make it work. Thanks in advance

```
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<label for="Name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />

<label for="City">City:</label>
<input type="text" name="City" id="City" />

<label for="Email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />

<label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
<textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Unless you post your PHP code, it's impossible for us to help you as we can't see what's happening outside of your HTML.

Comment: @relentless its the exact same code as the tutorial i posted a link to, its just not work on my site which i also posted a link to.

Answer (score 3):

If the code you posted is ALL of your PHP code then the issue is that you're not capturing the `$_POST` data.

i.e.

```
$subject ="$subject";
```

Should be:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

and so on...

ALSO

`"$subject"` is being treated as a string. If `$subject` is set elsewhere use `$subject`

Comment: Anywhere you want to use the user submitted data. Also, see @nickhar's answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first answer, from a brief scan, you're not executing the `mail` command either and turning it into a string:

```
$send_contact='mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)';
```

To execute it:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Comment: thank you this along with what relentless said did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You're not capturing the values of variables. You need to use `$_POST['nameAttribute']` to store the form inputs in PHP.

```
$subject ="$subject";
```

This declaration will not do what you expect it to. If you want to get the subject from the form, you'll have to add a new `<input>` field for that and then use the following to get the user input value:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject']; //assuming the name attribute was 'subject'
```

Also, your code that handles sending of email is incorrect, too. It is:

```
$send_contact='mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)';
```

You don't need to wrap it in single quotes. It should be:

```
$send_contact = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

So, finally after applying all the changes, it will look like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { //checking if form was submitted
$subject = "Your subject"; //subject
$city = $_POST['City'];
$mail_from = $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['Message'];

// From
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";
$to ='contact@kieshajewel.com';

$send_contact = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header); //sending email

if($send_contact)
{
echo "We've recived your contact information";
}
else
{
echo "ERROR";
}   

}
?>
```

Hope this helps!